# Make link in Send Dialog to Facebook application?

Tags: facebook, url, hyperlink, dialog, send

Hi so I am making a Facebook app which uses the send dialog. I was wondering why it doesn't work when I put 'https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME/' as my link parameter. I want the link in the send message to be a link to my app but on the send dialog is appears as apps.facebook.com. Is there anyway to do this?

Edit: Yes sorry here is the code:

```
<script>
FB.init({appId: 'App_ID', xfbml: true, cookie: true});
function sendMessage(){
  // assume we are already logged in
      var token = FB.getAuthResponse().accessToken;
      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'Test',
          link: 'https://www.apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME',
          description: 'This is a test',
          picture: '',
          display: 'iframe',
          access_token: token 
          });
}
 </script>
```

Comment: can you show any codes in which you placed the code  https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME/ ?

Comment: Are you sure it is "https://www.apps.facebook/APP_NAME" and not "https://apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME". If the link is broken, I don't know what is Facebook's reaction to it.

Comment: well idk how it could be apps.facebook/APP_NAME because the url when i go on my app is apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME. I will try that and let you know.

Comment: o wow lol sorry. i should fix that. idk why it showed up like that but yea i did do https://www.apps.facebook.com/APP_NAME

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want the apps.facebook.com domain showing up in the caption for the post, you ca theren create a new page in your site.  Set all the og meta tags to what you want to show up in the feed.  The only other content in the page should just be a javascript redirect to your you canvas app.  This way when FB scrapes your site, they get all the necessary data and when a user clicks on the link, the js redirects them to your app.

Also, there is not a "www" in the url for app canvas pages.